# Form submissions over time - compare the difference from last submission - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

I have a list of answers that comes in through a form in Google sheets like this. Please note that the answers in Column F & G are comma seperated

[image: form submissions]

I would like to end up with a list looking like this for the Name 'Test Mother'...

[image: expected result]

I merged all my added results and all my deleted results in two columns like this but when I try to look for the difference they take out both the instances of 'lo lo' because it has been deleted and put back again. What I need it to do is to leave one instance and take out the other.

[image: comparing columns]

I used this formula

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",true,unique(ArrayFormula(trim(split(textjoin(", ", true,B2:C2),","))),true,true))
```

I feel I might have gone down the rabbit hole with this one but it was the only way I could think of starting comparing the cells but as it takes our all the instances it doesn't give me the right result in the end.

The google sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BGo3uFN-1gTh8Ige46GqPF_3vUw6XGmuW4KLgEPfRMA/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(
 QUERY({A2:A&"¤", IF(F2:F="",,SUBSTITUTE(F2:F, " ", "×")&","), ROW(A2:A)}, 
 "select max(Col2) where not Col1 = '¤' 
  group by Col3 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "¤"), "×", " ")), ",$", ))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY((FILTER(TEXT(
 QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A9&"×"&SPLIT(F2:F9, ",")), "×")), 
 "where Col2 is not null", ), {"@♦", "@,"}), NOT(COUNTIF(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TEXT(
 QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A9&"×"&SPLIT(G2:G9, ",")), "×")), 
 "where Col2 is not null", ), {"@♦", "@,"})),,9^9))&COUNTIFS(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TEXT(
 QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A9&"×"&SPLIT(G2:G9, ",")), "×")), 
 "where Col2 is not null", ), {"@♦", "@,"})),,9^9)), FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TEXT(
 QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A9&"×"&SPLIT(G2:G9, ",")), "×")), 
 "where Col2 is not null", ), {"@♦", "@,"})),,9^9)), SEQUENCE(ROWS(TEXT(
 QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A9&"×"&SPLIT(G2:G9, ",")), "×")), 
 "where Col2 is not null", ), {"@♦", "@,"}))), "<="&SEQUENCE(ROWS(TEXT(
 QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A9&"×"&SPLIT(G2:G9, ",")), "×")), 
 "where Col2 is not null", ), {"@♦", "@,"})))), FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TEXT(
 QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A9&"×"&SPLIT(F2:F9, ",")), "×")), 
 "where Col2 is not null", ), {"@♦", "@,"})),,9^9))&COUNTIFS(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TEXT(
 QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A9&"×"&SPLIT(F2:F9, ",")), "×")), 
 "where Col2 is not null", ), {"@♦", "@,"})),,9^9)), FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TEXT(
 QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A9&"×"&SPLIT(F2:F9, ",")), "×")), 
 "where Col2 is not null", ), {"@♦", "@,"})),,9^9)), SEQUENCE(ROWS(TEXT(
 QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A9&"×"&SPLIT(F2:F9, ",")), "×")), 
 "where Col2 is not null", ), {"@♦", "@,"}))), "<="&SEQUENCE(ROWS(TEXT(
 QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A9&"×"&SPLIT(F2:F9, ",")), "×")), 
 "where Col2 is not null", ), {"@♦", "@,"})))))))), 
 "select max(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "♦")), ",$", ))
```

[image]